# Strange std::nan error

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, std

When I open my C++ Makefile project in Eclipse CDT, every std::nan is underlined in red, and I get this error when I mouse over:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
__gnu_cxx::enable_if<&0[std::__is_arithmetic<#0>::__value],int>::__type isnan(#0)
'
```

However, the project compiles perfectly, with no errors or warnings, with make + g++.  When I remove the std:: from std::isnan, Eclipse stops complaining, even though I'm not aware of any isnan function or macro outside the std namespace.  What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Eclipse CDT is known for having some issues parsing code.

Comment: CDT underlines every instance of `std::move` in my code with red squiggles, and shows some bizarre *candidates* when I hover over them. But the codes compiles and works great. I think it's just a CDT parser problem.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the other answers. They did not work this time (but had worked for other eclipse errors that really were not errors).  What I did was include the proper headers and namespace, then remove the "std::" from std::isnan.  The result - no error in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few cases where Eclipse needs an index refresh. On the project explorer in the left, right click on a source file and choose "`Index -> Freshen All Files`" and "`Index -> Re-Resolve Unresolved Includes`".